# Can I use 'where' as I do 'when' like the following?

Tags: sentence-usage

I'm familar with this sentence.

> When I play basket ball, I'm happy.

Then, How about 'where'? Can I use 'where' as I do 'when' like the following?

> Where I play basket ball, there are a lot of people.

Comment: Yes, that's good syntax.  But "basketball" is one word, not two.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, they just have different meanings due to the changed pronoun.

For instance, "When I play basketball, I'm happy", means that you are happy **whenever you are playing basketball** (e.g. time).

However, "Where I play basketball, there are lots of people", means that there are **lots of people at the place you play basketball**.

But to answer your main question, ***you can use "where" in this sentence***, but you could not use other common pronouns such as (what, how, who) without changing the structure of the sentence to a question form.

*When* and *Where* can be used in this context, but personally, I have found that when they are used like this, "whenever" and "wherever" are used instead, like this:

> Wherever I go, people follow me.
>
> Whenever  I go to a shop, I look around for hours before buying something.

When you are using the extended forms of these pronouns, you can use others, such as "whatever" or "whoever":

> Whatever I buy for my sister, she will like it.
>
> Whoever wins will receive a prize of £1000.

In conclusion, yes, you can use both when and where in that sentence. "Where" *should not be expanded* (to wherever) in your case, because you are saying the ***precise location***, so it is fine as it is.

As "when" can be expanded to make it more clear, these are the final sentences as I would say them:

> Whenever I play basketball, I am happy.
>
> Where I play basketball, there are lots of people.

**Edit**
Just to clear up, "where" means one location, and "wherever" means any location